# Substrate Error

Tags: substrate-node-template

we create a local blockchain using substrate following this steps:- (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain/) upto cargo build --release steps is completed.then i using command ./target/release/node-template --dev.but,I face this error.

Err message:-

```
2023-03-28 18:14:36 Substrate Node
2023-03-28 18:14:36 ✌️ version 3.0.0-dev-ae49625b5f7
2023-03-28 18:14:36 ❤️ by Parity Technologies admin@parity.io, 2017-2023
2023-03-28 18:14:36  Chain specification: Development
2023-03-28 18:14:36  Node name: encouraging-activity-5914
2023-03-28 18:14:36  Role: AUTHORITY
2023-03-28 18:14:36  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/substraterJpkV8/chains/dev/db/full
2023-03-28 18:14:36 ⛓ Native runtime: node-268 (substrate-node-0.tx2.au10)
2023-03-28 18:14:45 [0]  generated 1 npos voters, 1 from validators and 0 nominators
2023-03-28 18:14:45 [0]  generated 1 npos targets
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)"))) 2023-03-28 18:14:45 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("cannot deserialize module: UnknownOpcode(192)")
```

and i attached screenshoot to this message.

Thanks[image]

Comment: Mac m2? Please provide more information on your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
we are installed rustc version 1.68
we are installed cargo 
we followed by this reference link -> https://docs.substrate.io/install/linux/
@OliverTale-Yazdi

Comment: You still did not tell me whether you are using a Mac M2 or not. Anyway, the Q got closed as duplicate…

Comment: Hi @OliverTale-Yazdi Oops we are not using the Mac as a OS we are using ubuntu22.04LTS having the config of 8 GB RAM and 256 GB SSD.

Comment: Okay that is weird. Can you try again to run the node with `--execution wasm  --wasm-execution compiled`? It should not change anything, but just in case. Otherwise I have no idea what is going on. Seems to be a recent thing. Maybe check that the correct compiler is used with `cargo version` and `cargo +nightly version`.

Comment: Hi @OliverTale-Yazdi Thanks for your response!
we are using this below version:-
rustc 1.68.2 (9eb3afe9e 2023-03-27)
cargo version -> cargo 1.68.2 (6feb7c9cf 2023-03-26)
cargo +nightly version -> cargo 1.70.0-nightly (145219a9f 2023-03-27)

Comment: Did you read the linked answer? `solved by downgrading nightly from 1.70 to 1.68`. Then this Q is indeed a duplicate.